# Are there any downsides to this alternative to `useCallback` to avoid children re-rendering in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have come across some code that is used to avoid the recreation of functions during render than the official `useCallback` hook that I think has some benefits over `useCallback` but am curious if there are potential pitfalls to this approach.

Essentially `useCallback` is great because it lets you cache a function between renders provided the dependencies array values do not change. But what it does mean is that when those values change the function is a new function, and any child components that use that function will re-render. This is of course by design so that you don't have stale references to the values used in the callback.

This approach below I believe achieves the same thing but without ever creating a new method. It creates a single wrapper method, that never changes, and uses a ref to keep track of the latest version passed in, so when the callback is called it always has the latest version.

```
export function useConstantCallback<Args extends unknown[], Result>(
    providedCallback: Callback<Args, Result>
): Callback<Args, Result> {
    const providedCallbackRef = useRef<Callback<Args, Result>>(providedCallback);

    // if the function is new then update the callback ref 
    if (providedCallbackRef.current !== providedCallback) {
        providedCallbackRef.current = providedCallback;
    }

    const returnFunctionRef = useRef((...args: Args) => {
        // use last provided version when called
        return providedCallbackRef.current(...args);
    }).current;

    return returnFunctionRef;
}
```

Called very much the same as `useCallback` but without the dependencies array.

```
const myCallback = useConstantCallback(() => {
   if (someReferencedValue > 0){
      setState(true)
   }
})
```

One issue reading it that I'm not 100% sure is an issue is that it is creating refs during render, and also I'm not sure if these refs get disposed of properly. This code could probably be improved by putting it into a useEffect but I wanted to get stack overflows thoughts on this as I'm not sure what the downsides of this approach are.

The upsides are:

- Doesn't create a new function ever, so doesn't trigger re-render of children - Wheras useCallback will create a new function when the dependencies array changes.
- Still always calls the latest version so doesn't end up with stale references
- Doesn't require maintaining the dependency array at all

Comment: What stops you from passing empty dependency array to `useCallback`? As per the [official documentations](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback#updating-state-from-a-memoized-callback) it's perfectly fine

Comment: Because a) that would mean that the callback is the same everytime, thereby having stale references and b) I didn't write this and am trying to get understanding from others if there are downsides to this approach that I didn't write. I understand how useCallback works and if you are referencing values inside the callback you should not have empty array or it will end up with stale values.

Comment: I see the useful case where you pass `myCallback` as prop and use it as dependency to Child's `useEffect` the reference will stay the same so it won't cause it to re-run, while its prop `myCallback` will get updated values. However, the "*Doesn't create a new function ever, so doesn't trigger re-render of children*" is wrong as whenever Parent component re-renders it will cause its Children to re-render (*in this scenario*). But that's like a fact, not a downside nor an upside, I'll leave the downsides to someone that can calculate your code.

Comment: The returned method never gets recreated though is the point. In the case of useCallback the function will be a new function of the dependencies change so then any children to receive that function as a prop will rerender. In this case of this hook the function returned is a ref that wraps the called function. 

So I when parent rerenders, children never get a new reference and don’t rerender. But still get the new inner function and avoid stale references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there are significant downsides to your approach. In fact, the React team is considering doing something similar.

Personally, I'd go with `useCallback` with an empty dependency array, instead of the second `useRef` - it's more idiomatic React. And I don't think that conditionally setting the ref gains you much - I'd expect it to change all of the time regardless, and assignment is cheap.

```
export function useConstantCallback<Args extends unknown[], Result>(
    providedCallback: Callback<Args, Result>
): Callback<Args, Result> {
    const providedCallbackRef = useRef<Callback<Args, Result>>(providedCallback);

    providedCallbackRef.current = providedCallback;

    return useCallback((...args: Args) => {
        return providedCallbackRef.current(...args);
    }, []);
}
```

This ends up being very similar to the React team's proposed [useEvent](https://blog.logrocket.com/what-you-need-know-react-useevent-hook-rfc/) hook.  [Their implementation](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md#internal-implementation) has some nuances - there are corner cases around when the function is updated. They also list some cases it doesn't cover and some drawbacks: (See the RFC for full details.)

> When useEvent should not be used:
>
> - Functions called during render still use useCallback...
> - Not all functions in effect dependencies are events...
> - Not all functions extracted from effects are events...
>
> Drawbacks:
>
> - This adds a new concept to React. People are already struggling with the best practices around defining functions ("should I use `useCallback` everywhere?") and this adds another layer to it...
> - Compared to a plain event handler, wrapping with `useEvent` looks more noisy...
> - `useEvent` makes the "event handler" term broader than just the DOM event handlers...
> - Compared to `useCallback`, the implementation of `useEvent` adds extra work to the commit phase...
> - There are a few edge cases. However, we think they’re not dealbreakers...

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! That is what I thought. I wondered after at first not understanding this code (that I didn't write) and later understanding it, why react doesn't do something similar. Since it reduces re-renders significantly in some cases, and avoids having the overhead of managing the dependency array.